# py2exe: cannot import name 'socks' from 'httplib2'

Tags: python, py2exe

I tried using pyinstaller to get my .py file into an exe, but I cannot get the geemap package to bundle with it.

I am now trying to use py2exe, and I can see geemap is included in the library.zip file.

However, I get the following error when running the exe, and have tried importing http2lib already...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'socks' from 'httplib2 (C:\...\library.zip\httplib2\__init__.pyc)'
```

Comment: is the code running ok? it seems to be failing to import 'socks' what is the command you are running? 
is it something like this?
pyinstaller --clean -D --onedir -windowed --icon={imageName}.ico  {fileName}.py

Comment: I am using py2exe because pyinstaller was not working for me. But I used --onefile for pyinstaller, not --onedir or --clean ...